# How can I get EAPOL packet's number?

Tags: network, wifi, wpa2, wpa2-psk

I need to work with `EAPOL` packets, and I have to distinguish between first, second, third and fourth...

If I'm using `WPA2` I can use the first 2 bytes of `Key Information` field, and I can use `Key MIC`, `Secure`, `Encrypted Kedy Data`... But if I'm using `WPA` I can't use them because are always settled as zero...

So, have you any suggestion to me??

Comment: At risk of sounding facetious - don't use WPA.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I need to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it for both WPA and WPA2 using `MIC_SET`, `ACK` and `NONCE` fields.

```
MIC_SET   |   ACK   |   NONCE   |   Packet Number
   0      |    1    |     x     |        1
   1      |    0    |     x     |        2
   1      |    1    |     x     |        3
   1      |    0    |     0     |        4
```

Where with `x` I indicate that the NONCE has a value different of `0000000...`